# Unable to disable the hardware prefetcher

Tags: prefetch, msr

I am trying to disable the hardware prefetcher to run some memory benchmarks on an Intel core i5 2500. The problem is that there is no option whatsoever in my BIOS to enable or disable the prefetcher. So I am trying to use msr-tools to disable the prefetcher. But msr-tool is failing to write some specific values to the required register (0x1a0h).

```
$ rdmsr -p 0 0x1a0
850089

$ wrmsr -p 0 0x1a0 0x850289
wrmsr: CPU 0 cannot set MSR 0x000001a0 to 0x0000000000850289
```

This is the same case for all cpus. But if I try to write the value 0x850088 (simply chosen for testing) it will successfully write that value.

Can anyone point out as to where the problem is and what is the solution for this?

Also I felt weird that there is no prefetcher disabling option in my BIOS. Is this the situation with some version of BIOS?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Not exactly. This is a question related to disabling hardware prefetcher, however it might be done.

Comment: Ah, ok.  You might have better luck on [SU], in case you didn't know it was there.  It's in the same family of sites, and more geared towards this type of question I believe.

Comment: Use 0x1a4 as described in the following document: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Nehalem, Westmere, Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge, Haswell, or Broadwell Intel CPU, you can enable/disable various prefetchers with bits 0:4 of MSR 0x1a4. See: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors.html

```
# E.g. showing initially all enabled:
rdmsr -a -c 0x1a4
> 0xf
> <etc>

# Disable all 4 prefetchers, by setting all 4 bits:
wrmsr -a 0x1a4 $(( 2**0 | 2**1 | 2**2 | 2**3))
rdmsr -a -c 0x1a4
> 0xf
> <etc>
```

This gives a performance improvement of about 5% for me, with an application that has a random-access memory intensive workload.

For older Intel Core / NetBurst architectures, it seems to be a different MSR, 0x1a0, with the ability to enable/disable 2 different prefetchers via bits 9 and 19. See:

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/optimizing-application-performance-on-intel-coret-microarchitecture-using-hardware-implemented-prefetchers.html

To disable/enable them you might do something like (untested, cause I don't have a Core CPU - so I get an error if I try set these 2 bits):

```
MSRORIG=$(printf "0x%x\n" $(rdmsr -c 0x1a0)) 
# To set bits 9 and 19 and disable the prefetchers:
wrmsr -a 0x1a0 $((MSRORIG | 1<<19 | 1<<9))
# To unset and enable:
wrmsr -a 0x1a0 $((MSRORIG & ~(1<<19 | 1<<9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr -p $i 0x1a0 -f 3:0
```

L2 hardware prefetcher  - bit 0

L2 adjacent cache line prefetcher - bit 1

DCU prefetcher - bit 2

DCU IP prefetcher - bit 3

[1]

I get 9 as the response. If the bit is set that prefetcher is OFF.
L2 hardware prefetcher and DCU IP prefetecher are off for me.
To switch them on:

```
$ sudo rdmsr -p 0 0x1a0
850089
# now we update bits 0 and 3
$ sudo wrmsr -p 0 0x850080 # 0b1001 = 0x9 wheras 0b0000 = 0x0
# check it took
$ sudo rdmsr -p 0 0x1a0
850080
```

all prefetchers are now on

To switch them off it's similar
    $ sudo wrmsr -p0 0x85008f
    #this fails for me, I can set bit 1 so L2 adacent cache line prefetcher stays on 
    $ suod wrmsr -p0 0x85008d 
    # the others can be switched off

[1] https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors

Comment: I think you've mixed together the NetBurst / Core 0x1a0 prefetch MSR and the newer 0x1a4 MSR for Nehalem+.